# How to join two MySQL tables and check row status in second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm querying a table and needing to pull details from another one as well.

Here's the columns in the `payments` table

```
id, member, kwid, keyword, engine, start, ranking, price, month, year, sorter, status
```

This is the original query I was using to pull from the `payments` table:

```
SELECT member, SUM(price) AS revenue FROM payments WHERE status = 'Paid' GROUP BY member ORDER BY revenue DESC
```

That query works just as I want.  It gets a list of payments with the status set to Paid and groups by the member ID.

But, I also want to use that member id (`member`) to get that member's details from the `members` table.

Here's the columns in the `members` table:

```
id, company, domain, email, status
```

I've tried using INNER JOIN but can't seem to get it to work.

Here's that query:

```
SELECT member, SUM(price) AS revenue 
FROM payments t1 
WHERE status = 'Paid' 
GROUP BY member 
    INNER JOIN members t2 ON t1.member = t2.id 
ORDER BY revenue DESC
```

All I'm basically wanting to do is get the member's `company`, `email`, and `domain`.  And if the `status` of the member (in the `members` table) is NOT set to `Active`, I don't want to display it.

Comment: Show us the query you tried please

Comment: Also which column links `payments` to `members`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Just added the query.  The column `member` in the payments `table` should match the `id` column in the `members` table.

Comment: By the way, I've never used `INNER JOIN` before, so I may be doing it completely wrong...

Comment: I would expect that query with a join to be generating errors! Is it?

Comment: Yes, this is the error:  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN members t2 ON t1.member = t2.id ORDER BY revenue DESC LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Comment: Well that really should have made you check the manual or go looking for some tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all members and lots of columns, I would suggest a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT m.*,
       (SELECT SUM(p.price)
        FROM payments p
        WHERE p.member = m.id AND p.status = 'Paid' 
       ) as revenue
FROM members m
ORDER BY revenue DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the details from `members` and aggregate on a column of `payments` then start the join from `members` like this:

```
SELECT m.id, m.company, m.email, m.domain, 
  SUM(price) AS revenue 
FROM members AS m INNER JOIN payments AS p
ON p.member = m.id  
WHERE m.status = 'Active' AND p.status = 'Paid'
GROUP BY m.id, m.company, m.email, m.domain
ORDER BY revenue DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you are on the right track, the only think missing in your query is expanding the items in "select" to include the details you want from the "members" table.

try this and see how it goes :

```
SELECT member, company, email, domain, SUM(price) AS revenue 
FROM payments t1 
WHERE status = 'Paid' 
GROUP BY member 
     INNER JOIN members t2 ON t1.member = t2.id 
ORDER BY revenue DESC
```

Comment: @basic which part ?

Comment: This: GROUP BY member 
     INNER JOIN members t2 ON t1.member = t2.id